# killing the process with pid using a single line

Tags: shell

I have a multiple processes with a similar keyword. I have to kill all the process at one shot. Like

```
  ps -ef |grep raj
root      3129     1  0 15:32 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/raj/msisdn
root      3165     1  0 15:36 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/raj/raj-1.sh
root      3166  3165  0 15:36 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/raj/raj-2
root      3170  2236  1 15:36 pts/0    00:00:00 grep raj
```

I heard that this can be done using awk. One liner command to kill all the process is what I need :)

Comment: Like getting the pids alone and killing all those pids..

Comment: This question probably belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
pgrep -f raj | xargs kill
```

I'd recommend running

```
pgrep -f raj | xargs ps
```

first, to make sure you're killing the right processes.

**EDIT:** If you want to use awk, try:

```
ps -ef | grep raj | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

but it's more verbose than pgrep and kill.

Comment: pkill -9 -f raj    is even shorter